# Using original picture after preprocess function

Tags: views, theming

I have a preprocess function (function MYTHEME_preprocess_user_picture()) that scales and crops user pictures throughout the site and they become the default pictures.

How can I still have access to the original picture (non-cropped, non-scaled) for use in some parts of the site (Views for example)?  The "original" option in the views image select list has disappeared.

I am trying to avoid using image styles as the creation of different image styles slows down the site and takes room on the server (social networking site with many users.) Besides, using image styles also require a page refresh to see the pictures once uploaded. The preprocess function solves all these problems.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Thank you. :)

Comment: Generally preprocess functions are to alter the variables before they are theme. If you are saving something back, that's not a clever use of preprocess functions. 
Consider altering where users upload the picture and apply your alternations there.

Comment: Yes, but having to refresh the browser page after uploading an avatar to be able to see it, is extremely annoying. If I could just solve this issue, I could get rid of the preprocess function.

Comment: Are you using any modules to ajaxify the page?

Comment: No, I am not using any module to ajaxify the page..

Comment: "image styles slows down the site...The preprocess function solves all these problems". I don't agree with you. Image styles works fine and they are cached, you don't need to recreate images on each page load. But preprocess function will be triggered on each page load.

Comment: Yes, what you are saying is correct once the images with their different styles have been created. But when users upload avatars and pictures (and that happens a lot on a social network website) the server slows down a lot for creating all of those. I have been more successful in limiting the image style to one or two (the largest sizes) and using css to shrink the images when necessary.